# How to find url along with host

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to know the current route along with host how can I find out?
I tried but could not find the accurate answer.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `request.url`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails3, then use `request.fullpath`.

Comment: fullpath does not return the host

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
request.host  # for getting host
request.url # for getting complete url
```

See ActionDispatch::Http::URL API for more details.